# Is rubbing alcohol poisonous to shiitake mushrooms?

Tags: growth, mushrooms

Within 24 hours my shiitake log got covered with a lot of green mold from a manufacturer, and feel I should douse the log with alcohol to try to save it. would this be a good idea?

Comment: Don't use alcohol.  Green mold is probably just fine.  Please send a picture.  How is this LOG planted anyway?  That green 'mold' might be a copper sulfate they spray root ball burlap with so that it inhibits root growth.  Or it could be just a fungus that came alive with a little water.  No alcohol.  That could damage the cambium of your log.  I gotta know more, I have never 'planted' mushrooms'  I have seen  green mold covering my Gro-Co mulch within 24 hours after installation.  I just send someone out to rake lightly and it goes away, no more 'algae blooms'?

Comment: @stormy root ball on a shiitake kit in a box? It grew very quickly in 24 hours. it appeared on top of a wood chip (boiled for 90 minutes)/on the side of the log, and only plan to do it in a week after popping my head in it tomorrow when my inoculated box should be done. I do have a tiny bit of water sitting in the bottom of the tub to control moisture.

Comment: I have no idea of your setup.  Not a picture in my head. "Tub with a bit of water to control moisture"?  I am very out of it with mushrooms.  Please send some info on this kit.  Mushrooms are the 'genitalia' of a fungus right?  Mold is fungus.  Aren't you heavily into fungus this year?  Mycelium, mushrooms, spores.  It is usually all good, right?  Are you doing the composting in the aisles?  Sorry.  BT, please send some pictures, thanks a million.

Comment: found out i was dealing with trich

Comment: Trichomonas?  A human intestinal parasite that can also lead to STD's?  It is also anaerobic.  I find it interesting that the bloom came AFTER you opened the package?  Is that right?  How do you know it is TRICH?

Comment: i had a green layer that showed up under fuzz after flipping the log over, and it was the same fuzz i saw when i had a shitaki show up under it

Comment: Please send a picture.  Life under the salt and sand in Death Valley and the big Salt flats IS green.  They live in a mini greenhouse where they are able to hold onto the bit of water that falls beneath a layer of salt and sand.  Like algae?  Please send a picture, okay?

Comment: When I installed the mulch I WOULD use, this human poo mixed with sawdust and thoroughly decomposed, tested, you would be given a print out of the last of the 5 tests it went through in the process of decomposition.  No weed seeds, quite a bit of nitrogen after the decomp process, no pesticide residues, no sticks, stones...but right after installation when the mulch was finally exposed to oxygen it would turn green all over the surface...a fungus/mold.  We'd rake it once and it wouldn't turn green again.  I don't think there is any connection between green fungus and Shitake mushrooms.

Comment: Shoot, other than they are both fungi.  Have you ever looked into taking a Master Gardener Course?  That is where you learn the basics.  That is where you can ask these questions and be given straight answers.  No magic.  You would LOVE these courses.  Almost 'free' as well.  People who have no experience at all with plants leave these courses knowing the basics and can teach the basics.

Comment: i'm looking into it this year